# Polars: return dataframe with all unique values of N columns

Tags: python-polars

I have a dataframe that has many rows per combination of the 'PROGRAM', 'VERSION' and 'RELEASE_DATE' columns.  I want to get a dataframe with all of the combinations of just those three columns.  Would this be a job for `groupby` or `distinct`?

thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are not aggregating anything, use `unique`

```py
df.select(['PROGRAM','VERSION','RELEASE_DATE']).unique()
```

If you are not using the Lazy functionality of Polars, this can also be written as:

```py
df[['PROGRAM','VERSION','RELEASE_DATE']].unique()
```

Comment: Can the select version posted above be iterated on?

Comment: `for prog, vers, rel in df.select(['PROGRAM','VERSION','RELEASE_DATE']).distinct().rows(): ...`

Comment: `distinct()` has been deprecated, you should use `unique()` instead